# How to add a instance of class into a variable c#?

Tags: c#, .net

How to add a instance of class into a variable c#?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    var msg = new Param
    {
       type = "text",
       text = $"{ message[i].VlrParam.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")}"
    };

    // What I need to do to acumulate msg variable into a new variable?
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append the object to a list that exists outside of the loop, instead of just to a variable that only exists inside the loop.  For example:

```
var msgs = new List<Param>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    msgs.Add(new Param
    {
       type = "text",
       text = $"{ message[i].VlrParam.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")}"
    });
}
// here you have the list of Param objects created in your loop
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a list of Param

```cs
var listParam = new List<Param>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    var msg = new Param
    {
       type = "text",
       text = $"{ message[i].VlrParam.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")}"
    };

    listParam.Add(msg);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const int count = 8;
var messages = new Param[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var msg = new Param
    {
       type = "text",
       text = $"{ message[i].VlrParam.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")}"
    };        
    messages[i] = msg;
}
```